# Does a thread have to be created from and join back to the same thread?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a Python script which uses RabbitMQ and the pika module to receive messages from clients. Given a message "enable", the script is required to run a method in a new thread, and given a message "disable", the thread that started with "enable" now needs to terminate.

However, every time a message is received, pika triggers a callback method which I assume runs in a new thread, and once the message is done being handled, the callback thread terminates.

In that case, two callbacks in different threads start and terminate another thread. I noticed that when I attempt to join(), I get:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 940, in join
  raise RuntimeError("cannot join current thread")
```

Is there some rule that the same thread that starts another thread also has to join() it? Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

I initially thought the error means a thread is trying to join itself, but I'm convinced that's not the case, and the issue started ever since two different threads started creating and terminating the same thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the problem. The error message is telling you that a thread is trying to join *itself*. Basically like this:

```
def run():
    thread.join()

thread= Thread(target=run)
thread.start()
```

This doesn't make any sense, obviously. Hence the exception is thrown.

---

As for fixing this bug: It's hard to say what you're doing wrong without knowing what your program is doing. It's possible that your code will work if you remove the call to `.join()`, or it could be that you're calling `.join()` on the wrong thread. You'll have to debug that on your own.

Answer (score 2):

From the [threading documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join):

> join() raises a RuntimeError if an attempt is made to join the current thread as that would cause a deadlock. It is also an error to join() a thread before it has been started and attempts to do so raise the same exception.